# Is this phrase seem to be misfit here?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-usage

[Source](http://epaperbeta.timesofindia.com/Article.aspx?eid=31806&articlexml=1-killed-in-JK-as-mob-attacks-Army-16042016001026)

> Scores of scruffily dressed teens take up position along north Kashmir's Baramulla-Kupwara highway , **sharp stones and rocks on the road in front** demarcating their “zone“. Barely 200 meters away , policemen wielding batons and cane shields stare back.

The bold part , as seems to me, is not connected with the sentence with any verb or connector.For eg, *with sharp stones and rocks on the road in front*.Is it correctly used?

Comment: It is OK, but might be more understandable written "*with*  sharp stones and rocks". The phrase is describing the road demarcation.

Answer (score 1):

I disagree, it is not badly worded. It comes off as a deliberate, rhetorical decision made by the author. It fits in the sense that I get the feeling that this is supposed to be some kind of rough scenario. These scruffily dressed teens are in a *sharp* contrast and opposition to the policemen. It helps emphasize the "us vs. them" scenario.

You could include *with* as you suggested, but to me, it disrupts the flow of the sentence. I'm not exactly sure what the effect of this flow is though.